# font size will be increase on whole app textview when click image

Tags: java, android, textview, font-size

I have to develop one android application.

Here i have to click one image means automatically increase the font size on whole app textview.how can i develop these like iphone BBC news app . please give me some idea ???

**EDIT:**

please see [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/bbc-news/id377382255?mt=8).here see the 2nd image bottom -A +A image is there...that purpose is have to click that image means automatically increase and decrese the whole app textview fontsize.
how can we ll do in android app ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use imageview and implement onclicklisetner

XML

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/firsttv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="@string/prompt" />

<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
            android:onClick="onclickbtn"
            />
```

Java

Register:

```
TextView tv;

tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.firsttv);
```

Onclick

```
public void onclickbtn(View v){

tv.setTextSize(20);

        }
```

Comment: i like your answer...but i need to click that image means automatically increase the text size...like zoom the view.if i have to photo on zoom 50,100,150 means its changed like know..here also i have to click the that image means increase the font size automatically and change the textview font size on whole app.

Comment: Please explain your concern clearly i am unable to understand.

Comment: please see here.here see the 2nd image bottom -A +A image is there know...that purpose is have to click that image means automatically increase and decrease the whole app textview fontsize.https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/bbc-news/id377382255?mt=8

Comment: Ok.. so implement int count in your onclick and change the fontsize accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is implemented version of your query:

Java Code:

```
package com.anurag.increasefont;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    TextView tv;Button b1,b2;int count=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;        
    }

    public void increase(View inc){
    count++;
    if(count==1){tv.setTextSize(20);    }
    else if(count==2){tv.setTextSize(30);}
    else if (count>=3) {count=3;tv.setTextSize(40);}
        }

    public void decrease(View dec){
        count--;
        if(count<=0){tv.setTextSize(12);count=0;}
        if(count==1){tv.setTextSize(20);}
        else if(count==2){tv.setTextSize(30);}
        else if (count==3) {tv.setTextSize(40);}
    }
}
```

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="This is sample text, i will increase and decrease the font size when user clicks on A+ and A_ buttons provided below. I can also use imageview or image button instead of Buttons to perform the same" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:onClick="decrease"
        android:text="Decrease" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="increase"
        android:text="Increase" />
</RelativeLayout>
```